# FxCop - CA1034 error - WHY?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, fxcop

I am running static code analysis with FxCop 1.36 and I keep getting [warning CA1034](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx): NestedTypesShouldNotBeVisible.

I would understand if the parent class were declared as internal or private, but it is public.  Why would it be bad for TimerReset to be declared public?

Am I missing something, or is this something that can be ignored?

Thanks for any input!

Here is an excerpt of the code causing this warning:

```
namespace Company.App.Thing
{
    public partial class Page : XtraPage
    {
        public delegate void TimerResetDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
        private TimerResetDelegate _timerReset;

        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public TimerResetDelegate TimerReset
        {
            set
            {
                if (null != (_timerReset = value))
                {
                    checkBox.Click += new EventHandler(_timerReset);
                    textField.Click += new EventHandler(_timerReset);
                    textField.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(_timerReset);
                    TimeField.Click += new EventHandler(_timerReset);
                    TimeField.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(_timerReset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `EventHandler`?

Comment: That was my question as well.

Comment: Just a FYI for any curious readers: instead of defining a `set` or `get/set` on such a 'purely technical' property `TimerReset`, it's better to write it as an `event` with `add/remove`. [see MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, Nested Types are harder to 'discover'.

E.g. To use your nested type, I will have to write following

```
Page.TimerResetDelegate timer = new Page.TimerResetDelegate();
```

Even though above is valid C# code, it doesn't read like the usual type usage.

Nested Types are generally used when you want to define a type to be used internally and you would avoid code like above. This is the reason why FxCop is giving you warning. If you want, you can ignore it. Personally, I would keep my Nested types as private. If I expect caller to make use of the type, I will move them to a proper namespace.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would it be bad for TimerReset to be declared public?

Exactly as the [description states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx):

> Nested types are useful for encapsulating private implementation details of the containing type. Used for this purpose, nested types should not be externally visible.

Since you're exposing `TimerResetDelegate` publically with `TimerReset`, I guess it's not an implementation detail.

> Do not use externally visible nested types for logical grouping or to avoid name collisions; instead, use namespaces.

Which makes it look like you're using a nested type for grouping. As FxCop states, use a namespace instead.

> Nested types include the notion of member accessibility, which some programmers do not understand clearly.

Since `TimerResetDelegate` is a delegate, this doesn't really apply.

Move `TimerResetDelegate` to it's own TimeResetDelegate.cs file, and put it in your `Company.App.Thing` namespace. Then, it's no longer nested.

Of course, it'd be even better to just go with [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) instead of defining your own delegate type.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your delegate is a type, but it is defined within the Page class.  I would just define it in the Company.App.Thing namespace, but it is not a problem really.  If you were writing an API it would just make it a bit messy, that's all.

Also, it is a bit odd to return the delegate like that, but I guess I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not **returning** a delegate. This is a set-only property, it's meant to set/register a handler. `Page.TimerReset = new handler(...)`. I suppose the OP didn't know that it is possible to write add/remove in an event, and that's why he decided to use property setter.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this is an FxCop rule that can be ignored.

There is nothing wrong from a CLR level with having a nested class.  It is just a guideline rule added to FxCop because the authors felt it was less usable or a poorer design than making the class non-nested.

Comment: FxCop is warning about the nested type being public not about using the nested type.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently it doesn't like the idea of nested classes, when they might be used outside the context of your Page class.

I personally agree with that in principle, though I can imagine some exceptions where it might be desirable.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Basically, it just summarizes the problem.